# How can I calculate which verticies make up each triangle in a polygon?

Tags: java, math, geometry

I am currently playing around with Opengl and I'm trying to create a class that can automatically calculate the vertex buffer data and element buffer data for a polygon.

Here is the code for creating the vertex data:

```java
        float centerangle = (float)(2*Math.PI / sides);
        ArrayList verticies = new ArrayList<Float>();

        for (int i=0; i<sides; i++) {
            float angle = (i*centerangle);
            float x = (float)Math.round(Math.cos(ang))/2f;
            float y = (float)Math.round(Math.sin(ang))/2f;
            float z = 0.0f;

            verticies.add(x);
            verticies.add(y);
            verticies.add(z);

        }

        return verticies;
```

Given that `sides == 5` this method creates the following values:

```
float[] {
    0.5, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.5, 0.0,
   -0.5, 0.5, 0.0,
   -0.5, -0.5, 0.0,
    0.0, -0.5, 0.0
}
```

I'm trying to create a method that will now generate the element buffer data. As of right now i have it hard coded. As an example, for the pentagon the element buffer data looks like this:

```java
        new int[] {
                1,2,3,
                3,1,4,
                0,1,4
        };
```

This creates 3 triangles [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RSOD.png)

So my question is is there a way i can calculate the element buffer data for any polygon that my method creates? What would that look like?

Answer (score 1):

For convex polygon you can use simple method - choose three top vertices, make triangle, then at every step make new triangle geting the topmost unused vertex (strip triangles up to down). Also [fan triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fan_triangulation).

If polygon might be concave, you need more sophisticated approaches for **polygon triangulation** (note this is not the same as point cloud triangulation). [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation) describes some algorithms in short.

Arbitrary found examples of Java implementation of ear-clipping: [one](https://github.com/earcut4j/earcut4j), [two](http://www.java2s.com/example/java/2d-graphics/computes-the-triangulation-of-a-polygon-with-earclipping-algorithm.html)